# Error creating contracts on Ethereum wallet

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, tokens

First of all, I'd like to provide a disclaimer. **I'm not a developer**, I never studied codes, and never wrote scripts since I was 14 years old. I'm doing this project for the company I work in at the moment, and as I was trying to create a token through ethereum, I constantly receive this error:

```
"throw" is deprecated in favour of "revert()", "require()" and "assert()".
        if (_to == 0x0) throw;                               
// Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
                        ^---^,
```

This error pops up every time I type in the code provided by ethereum, their template. I do not know why this is happening, nor  do I know how to fix it. I looked everywhere online, but I cannot seem to find anyone else facing the same issue. 
How do I fix this? am I doing this wrong? it is the first time I try to deploy a contract on the server and not on the test net.
Thank you in advance!

Here's the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;
contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }

contract MyToken {
/* Public variables of the token */
string public standard = 'Token 0.1';
string public name;
string public symbol;
uint8 public decimals;
uint256 public totalSupply;

/* This creates an array with all balances */
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

/* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

/* This notifies clients about the amount burnt */
event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

/* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
function MyToken(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    uint8 decimalUnits,
    string tokenSymbol
    ) {
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
    totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total supply
    name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
    symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
}

/* Send coins */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    if (_to == 0x0) throw;                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
    if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
}

/* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
    returns (bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    return true;
}

/* Approve and then communicate the approved contract in a single tx */
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
    returns (bool success) {
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        return true;
    }
}        

/* A contract attempts to get the coins */
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    if (_to == 0x0) throw;                                // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
    if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
    if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;     // Check allowance
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                           // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                             // Add the same to the recipient
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

function burn(uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;            // Check if the sender has enough
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                      // Subtract from the sender
    totalSupply -= _value;                                // Updates totalSupply
    Burn(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
}

function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                // Check if the sender has enough
    if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;    // Check allowance
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
    totalSupply -= _value;                               // Updates totalSupply
    Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
}
```

}

The code is from [the ethereum.org token example](https://ethereum.org/token)

Comment: Please, put your code or where you are using this "throw".

Comment: what about if (now < closingTime && msg.value > 0 && (privateCreation == 0 || privateCreation == msg.sender)) { etc } throw; ?

Comment: @Hus `require(now < closingTime && msg.value > 0 && (privateCreation == 0 || privateCreation == msg.sender)); { etc }`

Answer (score 9):

`throw` was deprecated in solidity version [0.4.13](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.13). You need to replace each line that says `if(condition) throw;` with `require(opposite of condition);`. For example:

```
if (_to == 0x0) throw;
```

becomes

```
require(_to != 0x0);
```

`throw` is used a number of times throughout your code, you need to change every one

Answer (score 1):

so it will be this one:

```
    /* Send coins */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    require (_to != 0x0) ;                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value);           // Check if the sender has enough
    if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
}
```

OR:

```
    /* Send coins */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    require (_to != 0x0) ;                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) require;           // Check if the sender has enough
    if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) require; // Check for overflows
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
}
```

.. if () require; or without?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning and your code should still get compiled successfully.

You can check out below link regarding the open issue on Github about completely deprecating `throw`.

[Depricating throw](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/1793)

`throw` will consume all you gas where as `revert` will return the unused gas.

you can also go through [solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions).